# Can't access flash drive on kali

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, flash-memory

I have flash drive but it can not be detect on kali and ubuntu. Windows can detect it but can't format it. Even in `gparted` it isn't listed. I refresh devices on `gparted` and get a warning:

```
Libparted Bug Found! Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 1):

I/O errors on flash drives usually point to hardware failure in the flash drive device itself.  This can happen when you overuse a flash drive, or if it is damaged some how (you sat on it and it became bent for instance, breaking internal components); this is known to happen also as a result of wear and tear on some drives over the lifetime of the flash drive.  I've had this happen with several (OLD) flash drives.  Usually, this isn't a fixable problem, and you have to accept that the flash drive is likely busted.

What further supports this answer is that Windows can 'detect' it as a device but not actually read the disk itself, and both Kali and Ubuntu see I/O errors.  (check `lsusb` to see if the device is 'detected' as well, it's likely being detected but the storage on-board is damaged in such a way your flash drive is not recoverable or usable again).  It's fairly likely that the drive is not usable anymore.

If you have another system (doesn't matter if Windows or Linux), test the flash drive there.  If that system also has issues accessing the data on the disk (can't detect partition types, I/O errors, etc.), then it's likely the issue stated here - your flash drive is damaged and is no longer usable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it isn't old I think it is a software problem I only work with gparted to format it and disks on ubuntu. I enter lsusb and don't know which is my flash drive

Comment: @Vesal75 this is why you can [**edit your question**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/243326/edit) and add the output of commands there.  Typically this happens with old flash drives to me, but it *does* happen sometimes with newer drives.  So far, I've had 5 out of 20 brand new out of the box flash drives I/O error on me.  It's not just an age issue, it could be a defect in the manufacturing, or any of a billion other issues.  If you have another system, test the drive there, and see if the I/O issues persist (to rule out your Kali/Ubuntu or the affected system's hardware/usb ports)